# Checking dates with Excel conditional formatting

Tags: excel, date, conditional-formatting

I am making a document to keep track of things that happen on a weekly basis and I want to implement conditional formatting as a way to make sure I catch user errors. I have one column with the start date and one with the end date, which will normally be 6 days away from the start because it is 1 week. I want the cell to turn red if I input a value that does not fit this assumption.

Example table:

[image: Example table with the incorrect date in red]

In the 'Edit Formatting Rule' menu I have tried:

Format only cells that contain | Cell Value | not equal to | =($A2+6) |

but it just made *everything* red.

Comment: https://excelchamps.com/blog/data-validation-date-range/

Comment: Message I get on Mac if I enter 24/12/2019 in A1 with the above Data Validation added https://i.stack.imgur.com/MnIjO.png https://i.stack.imgur.com/HgpOf.png (In UK where Date format is DD/MM/YYYY)

Comment: JGFMK I think that would have the same issue as before, only it doesn't let the user input anything. I think the problem is that the logic in   cell value = $A2+6  is somehow failing.

Comment: if you link some sample data perhaps it can be fixed. It may be that DATE() function will allow +6, but perhaps not a string literal. Put a sample in Googledocs, and link it. You can upload/download from/to Excel

Comment: With the correct logic the solution on http:excelchamps.com/blog/data-validation-date-range does an extreme version of what I wanted. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Oh I found it out. The problem was in $A2. apparently you have to use $A1 to get to the same row. Would this mean Excel uses cell names differently in conditional format than normal cells?

[image: cell value | not equal to | =$A1+6]

Comment: It has to do with your `Applies to:` range.  The row must coincide with the first row in that range.